# How to troubleshoot an expected CDROM device on custom Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm looking for some hints while troubleshooting missing CDROM device.

The problem is, missing configuration option for my custom kernel (linux-5.4.78).

My current .config has:

```
CONFIG_CDROM=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SR=y

CONFIG_VHOST_SCSI=y
CONFIG_BLK_SCSI_REQUEST=y
CONFIG_SCSI_MOD=y
CONFIG_SCSI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DMA=y
CONFIG_SCSI_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_SCSI_PROC_FS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_SPI_ATTRS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_FC_ATTRS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_ISCSI_ATTRS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_SAS_ATTRS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_SAS_LIBSAS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_SAS_HOST_SMP=y
CONFIG_SCSI_LOWLEVEL=y
CONFIG_ISCSI_TCP=y
CONFIG_ISCSI_BOOT_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_CXGB3_ISCSI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_CXGB4_ISCSI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_BNX2_ISCSI=y
CONFIG_BE2ISCSI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_HPSA=y
CONFIG_SCSI_3W_9XXX=y
CONFIG_SCSI_3W_SAS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_ACARD=y
CONFIG_SCSI_AACRAID=y
CONFIG_SCSI_AIC7XXX=y
CONFIG_SCSI_AIC79XX=y
CONFIG_SCSI_AIC94XX=y
CONFIG_SCSI_HISI_SAS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_HISI_SAS_PCI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_MVSAS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_MVSAS_TASKLET=y
CONFIG_SCSI_MVUMI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DPT_I2O=y
CONFIG_SCSI_ADVANSYS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_ARCMSR=y
CONFIG_SCSI_ESAS2R=y
CONFIG_SCSI_MPT3SAS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_MPT2SAS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_SMARTPQI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_UFSHCD=y
CONFIG_SCSI_UFSHCD_PCI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_UFSHCD_PLATFORM=y
CONFIG_SCSI_UFS_CDNS_PLATFORM=y
CONFIG_SCSI_UFS_HISI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_UFS_BSG=y
CONFIG_SCSI_HPTIOP=y
CONFIG_SCSI_BUSLOGIC=y
CONFIG_SCSI_FLASHPOINT=y
CONFIG_SCSI_MYRB=y
CONFIG_SCSI_MYRS=y
CONFIG_VMWARE_PVSCSI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_SNIC=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DMX3191D=y
CONFIG_SCSI_FDOMAIN=y
CONFIG_SCSI_FDOMAIN_PCI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_GDTH=y
CONFIG_SCSI_ISCI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_IPS=y
CONFIG_SCSI_INITIO=y
CONFIG_SCSI_INIA100=y
CONFIG_SCSI_PPA=y
CONFIG_SCSI_IMM=y
CONFIG_SCSI_STEX=y
CONFIG_SCSI_SYM53C8XX_2=y
CONFIG_SCSI_SYM53C8XX_MMIO=y
CONFIG_SCSI_IPR=y
CONFIG_SCSI_IPR_TRACE=y
CONFIG_SCSI_IPR_DUMP=y
CONFIG_SCSI_QLOGIC_1280=y
CONFIG_SCSI_QLA_FC=y
CONFIG_SCSI_QLA_ISCSI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_LPFC=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DC395x=y
CONFIG_SCSI_AM53C974=y
CONFIG_SCSI_WD719X=y
CONFIG_SCSI_PMCRAID=y
CONFIG_SCSI_PM8001=y
CONFIG_SCSI_BFA_FC=y
CONFIG_SCSI_VIRTIO=y
CONFIG_SCSI_CHELSIO_FCOE=y
CONFIG_SCSI_LOWLEVEL_PCMCIA=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DH=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DH_RDAC=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DH_HP_SW=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DH_EMC=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DH_ALUA=y
CONFIG_ISCSI_TARGET=y
CONFIG_ISCSI_TARGET_CXGB4=y
CONFIG_QED_ISCSI=y
```

I'm expecting to see /dev/sr0. It's not there. dmesg is mute about sr0.

However, I'm able to see it using stock kernel and I've identified it was bring by BLK_DEV_SR on my target:

```
# ls -l /dev/sr0
brw-rw---- 1 root optical 11,0 Apr 21 15:02 /dev/sr0

# readlink /sys/dev/block/11\:0/device/driver
../../../../../../../../../../../../bus/scsi/driver/sr
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Look on the stock kernel for which device driver is managing the device.

Comment: @stark it is `sr`

Comment: You have all the needed SCSI options turned on in your config?

Comment: @stark I zgrepped stock's config for `CONFIG_SCSI` and included in mine, still no `sr0`

Answer (score 0):

If your custom linux has `udev`, try `udevadm monitor`.

When you eject or insert a cd, you should see a change event on the terminal with the device path.

Also it's normally standard for a cdrom drive, no matter the actual device path, to be forwarded to `/media/cdrom`